# Open directly Play Framework in Fedora 19

Tags: linux, playframework, playframework-2.0, fedora

I have got a problem. I'm new to Fedora and Frameworks. In the Play Framework documentation says:

```
On UNIX systems, this means doing something like: 
export PATH=$PATH:/relativePath/to/play
```

So I did in ./bashrc:

```
#PATH 
export PATH=$PATH:/home/jx/Frameworks/play2
```

The problem is that I can't open the framework anywhere. (I.E. $ play help).

I can only open as follows :

```
[root@localhost play2]# ./play help
```

That is, I have to go to the directory of the framework.

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Comment: Did you restart your console after changes to bashrc ?

Answer (score 0):

You edited your path informations in `./bashrc` whereas you should edit `~/.bashrc`.

Once you've edited the right file, you can use it directly launching `. ~/.bashrc` (you have to do it in every *already opened* terminal) or just... restart your session.